# Value counts within col

Tags: python, pandas, list

How could I calculate the value counts within a string col?

```
df col
0 fruit["apple"], colour["green", "yellow" ] 
1 colour["yellow"] 
2 colour["brown"]
```

Expected Output

```
fruit  1
colour 3
```

Comment: What's the output of `df.head(3).to_dict()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extractall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) with substrings joined by `|` for regex or:

```
s = df['col'].str.extractall('(fruit|colour)')[0].value_counts()
print (s)
colour    3
fruit     1
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Or get words before `[` for more dynamic solution:

```
s = df['col'].str.extractall(r'(\w+)\[')[0].value_counts()
print (s)
colour    3
fruit     1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: is there an alternative way by any chance? pandas on spark doesn't yet allow ```extractall``` unfortunately

Comment: @arv working str.findall ?

Comment: would it be possible to add a new column with the unique values, next to the count? So we would have an extra column with ```[apple]``` in the first row, and ```[green, yellow, brown]``` in the second row